# Delete last element from dynamic array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I was making a `std::vector` like clone for a fun little project in C++, and I've come across the following problem: I'm trying to implement the method `pop_back` but for some reason, I can't get it to work. The class I'm using is called `Array` and is defined in `../d_arrays/d_array.h` and `../d_arrays/d_array.cpp` I have a `main.cpp` file in the root folder. Here is what I have so far:

RootDir/d_arrays/d_array.h

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Array {

    public:

        Array(int len);

        void pop_back();
        void print();

    private:
        
        int* _array = NULL;
        int _len = 0;

};
```

RootDir/d_arrays/d_array.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "d_array.h"

using namespace std;

Array::Array(int len) {
    _array = new int[len];
    _len = len;
}

void Array::pop_back() {
    _len--; // reduce length by 1

    int* tmp = new int[_len]; // create temp copy

    for (int i = 0; i < _len; i++) {
        tmp[i] = _array[i];
    }

    _array = tmp;
    delete[] tmp;
}

void Array::print() {
    for (int i = 0; i < _len; i++) {
        cout << _array[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

RootDir/main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

#include "d_arrays/d_array.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {

    Array a = Array(10);

    cout << "Before: ";
    a.print();
    a.pop_back();
    cout << "After: ";
    a.print();

    return 0;

}
```

Im using `g++ -o main main.cpp d_arrays/d_array.cpp` to compile my code and `./main` to run it.

whenever I run `./main` I get the following output:
`Before: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0`
`After: 0 0 118968336 21854 0 0 0 0 0`
What is happening here?

Comment: 1. I would seriously suggest not resizing arrays for every `pop_back`. 2. The array's contents are never initialized in the initial array, thus, using any of those values is undefined. 3. You also `delete[] tmp` which is the new array you just allocated.

Comment: try `std::swap(_array, tmp);` instead of `_array = tmp;`

Comment: Your problem is here: `_array = tmp; delete[] tmp;` You deleted the new array since both `tmp` and `_array` point to the same memory.

Comment: `len--; // reduce length by 1` -- And that is all you really need to do.  All of that other code that attempts to resize the memory allocated is not necessary.

Comment: @ChrisMM I used what you suggested and it works, I appreciate the answer!  `std::swap(_array, tmp);
    delete[] tmp;` is what I switched.

Comment: @Verve -- If your goal is to make a vector-like clone, `pop_back()` is supposed to be a constant-time operation.  Your `pop_back()` has linear time complexity, all due to the creation of memory and recopying.  Imagine if the vector had a million elements -- `pop_back()` would go through the gauntlet of decreasing the length (ok), but then reallocate 999,999 elements again and initialize them with data that you just deallocated.  That does not make a lot of sense, especially since `_len` is what controls the number of entries.

Comment: @Verve -- You should refer `delete`-ing the memory for very specific reasons: 1) In the destructor, 2) During a "trim_to_fit" call.  3) In a call to `clear()` 4) During a resize (to a larger size than the current capacity).  Which brings up the point -- there should be another member that holds the capacity, not just the length.  Since again, your goal is to create a vector-like clone, these things need to be taken into consideration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
delete[] tmp;
```

Now:

```
_array = tmp
```

means:

> Point _array to the memory address that tmp is pointing to.

Now, _array is pointing to &tmp (& means 'address of'), and then you delete tmp, which causes issues.

Also resizing the entire array would be ok if the array is small. But it would not be ok if the array is big. For example, if the array contains millions of elements, resizing the array is going to take a long time. So you can just not resize the array, as _len is what handles the number of elements.

So the new pop_back function can be as follows:

```
void Array::pop_back() 
{
    _len--; // reduce length by 1

    /* int* tmp = new int[_len]; // create temp copy

    for (int i = 0; i < _len; i++) 
    {
        tmp[i] = _array[i];
    }

    _array = tmp; 
    delete[] tmp; */
}
```

As you can see I've commented out all code except _len--;

But if you really want to resize the array at some point, you can declare a separate function for that as such:

```
void Array::shrink_to_fit()
{
    int* tmp = new int[_len]; // create temp copy

    for (int i = 0; i < _len; i++)
    {
        tmp[i] = _array[i];
    }

    delete[] _array; // Delete what _array is pointing to
    _array = tmp; // Point _array to the memory address that tmp is pointing to
}
```

But with this new function, don't forget to define shrink_to_fit() in your class definition. So the new class definition:

```
class Array 
{
public:

    Array(int len);

    void pop_back();
    void print();
    void shrink_to_fit();

private:

    int* _array = NULL;
    int _len = 0;
};
```

Comment: I really appreciate the answer and explanation!